# How to pass multiple parameters from controller in node.js express

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I am working with Passport, and I need to pass multiple parameters through to from my controller to my router. Basically it only passes the first one.

I want to get

```
app.get('/auth/steam', controllers.auth.authenticate);
```

to result in

```
app.get('/auth/steam', passport.authenticate('steam'), function(req, res) { res.render('index') };);
```

Right now it only loads the 1st parameter.

My controller looks like this

```
exports.authenticate =
  passport.authenticate('steam'),
  function(req, res) {
    res.render('index');
  };
```

How would I do this?

EDIT: I want to only be able to call it with **controllers.auth.authenticate**, not in an array like: **controllers.auth.authenticate[0]**!

Answer (score 0):

**Warning** NOT tested.

You can wrap all inside function

```
exports.authenticate = function(req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('steam', function(err, user, info) {
    if (err) { return next(err); }
    if (!user) { return res.redirect('/auth/steam'); }

    res.render("index");
  });
}
```

Or you can use `router` and protect ALL verbs (get, post, etc)

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.use(function (req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('steam'); 
});

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render("index");
});

module.exports = router;
```

And use router on the app

```
var ctrl = require("yourModuleName");
app.use('/auth/steam', ctrl); // app.use NOT app.get
```

Other alternative is to protect only the `get`

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', passport.authenticate('steam'), function(req, res, next) {
  res.render("index");
});

module.exports = router;

var ctrl = require("yourModuleName");
app.use('/auth/steam', ctrl); // app.use NOT app.get
```

See [Express routing](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html) page